# Datasets cached by different Vowpal Wabbit releases

Tags: caching, machine-learning, vowpalwabbit

Due to certain reasons, I'm using 2 different VW releases: the latest development version (8.1.1) for my experiments, and the "latest stable" 7.10 release for production. So, the question is: what happens if I simply specify `-c` flag for the production model, while training on the same dataset that was used by 8.1.1 Vowpal Wabbit?

- Will it rebuild the cache from scratch?
- Will it just reuse the previously saved cache? If this is the case, are the binary formats compatible for different VW releases?

I bumped into the following sentence in the [docs](https://github.com/JohnLangford/vowpal_wabbit/wiki/Tutorial#vws-diagnostic-information):

> If the cache exists and is newer than the data-set, it will be used, if it doesn't exist, it'll be created the first time -c is used.

Does it hold for different releases as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [source code](https://github.com/JohnLangford/vowpal_wabbit/blob/master/vowpalwabbit/parser.cc#L165-L183), the **cache** is rebuilt if the version stored in the cache file is different than the current VW version.

I think the cache format does not change so often, so maybe you can risk it and disable the check. I am not sure about 8.1.1 and 7.10 cache compatibility.

A different question is the compatibility of trained **models**. Here are some attempts to keep backward compatibility (newer VW can read older models) and I think even forward compatibility unless specific features are used. See [vw_versions.h](https://github.com/JohnLangford/vowpal_wabbit/blob/master/vowpalwabbit/vw_versions.h). At least VW should detect if the model (and cache) file is too old (two years ago it just crashed without any hint what's the reason).

Answer (score 2):

Current VW stores version info in cache file. While reading it checks that cache version matches its version and [recreates](https://github.com/JohnLangford/vowpal_wabbit/blob/master/vowpalwabbit/parser.cc#L180) cache file if they are not equal. So cache files made in one version of VW can't be used in another.